# Get object type from FieldNode in a GraphQL validator

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I'm writing a authorization component to validate GraphQL queries.

Using the `ValidationContext`object I manage to get the operation type (mutation/query), operation name and the non-scalar field names contained in the query.

What I need is to get the GraphQL type of these non-scalar fields.

Here is the code I'm using for the validator (using Typescript):

```
let entitiesArray:Array<string> = new Array<string>()

function getRecursiveSelectionSetNodes (selSetNode:SelectionSetNode) {
  selSetNode.selections.forEach ((node:FieldNode, index, array) => {
    if (node.selectionSet) {
      entitiesArray.push(node.name.value) // I could push the whole node, and make an array of nodes if necessary 
      getRecursiveSelectionSetNodes (node.selectionSet)
    }
  })
}

export const authorizeQuery = function authorizeQuery (context: ValidationContext): any {

  let opNode:OperationDefinitionNode = getOperationAST(context.getDocument())

  let opType = opNode.operation
  console.log ('_________________ AUTH OPERATION TYPE: ', opType)

  let opFieldNode:FieldNode = <FieldNode>opNode.selectionSet.selections[0]
  let opName = opFieldNode.name.value

  console.log ('_________________ AUTH OPERATION NAME: ', opName)

    let selSetUser:SelectionSetNode = opFieldNode.selectionSet
  // Selected fields by the user
  // Here, first-level nodes will be objects requested by the query
  // The nodes without a nested "SelectionSet" node will be scalar
  // Nodes with a nested "SelectionSet" are non-scalar that need to be checked

  getRecursiveSelectionSetNodes (selSetUser)

  console.log ('_________________ AUTH ENTITIES: ', JSON.stringify(entitiesArray))

  return []

}
```

This code returns the field names, not the type, so I need to map the field name "users" with the graphQL type "User[]", and so on, so I can perform authorization based on the graphql type being requested.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe a little more details would help... what does your shema look like? use it users: [User] ?   Also please formulate your question properly: "Any idea?" What are you after?

Comment: Hi Olivier. I'll edit my question to include more detail. About the "Any idea?" question, it refers to the beginning of the post, so the complete question would be "Any idea [on how to get the GraphQL type from the field name that I'm extracting from the AST]?" Thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the methods available on ValidationContext ? Is it on graphql-js?

Comment: Sure, the Typescript definition is here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/354cec620daccfa0ad167ba046651fb5fef69e8a/types/graphql/validation/validate.d.ts And yes, it's on graphql-js, here: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/validation/validate.js